# Get how many times a rule was used to buy

Tags: magento-1.9

Would there be any way for me to know how many times a promotion rule was used to buy products in magento? Is there a table that saves this data?

Comment: You need to get this info programmatically or just as a info for the store owner (as this would be available in the backend already)?

Comment: I need to simply visualize this, to have a control over some rules.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out `Reports > Sales > Coupon` in backend.

In this report you will be able to get a list of coupons used by your customers. You can specify a date range (mandatory), a particular order status (or all) and a specific coupon code (or all).

Please note that the data is fetched on a regular basis by the scheduler (the task relevant for this report is `aggregate_sales_report_coupons_data`) hence your cron jobs must be up an running to review this data (else you may have to refresh the stats manually whenever needed).

Comment: This is for rules that have coupons, is there any other way to see this for rules that do not use coupons? I give discounts for parameters in the url, so it automatically picks up and applies the discount, how could I recover it?

Comment: @GustavoSouza - What do you mean by giving discount parameters in the url? Can you update your question with more details as based on the given description I just can assume that you use a common setup - where else your comment now makes me wonder how you even apply the discounts. You do create shopping cart price rules from backend, right?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't get order reports based on cart rules which doesn't have coupon code associated with it

so this reports need to be generated through custom sql queries
refer the table `sales_order` and column is `applied_rule_ids` where you can find rule id's so based on that you can prepare you reports

Note: if order contains multiple rules in it then applied_rule_ids has comma seperated values so consider that case too and if you prefer to get shipped orders report add order status filter accordingly